# Kanban in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We plan to use Kanban in our DevOps project. It however looks like I still need to create Iterations (e.g. 14 days) and map the Kanban widget to show the WIP over the 14 day cycle.

So, in essence I still need to create Iterations. And a follow up understanding accordingly is that I will need to do sprint planning for the iterations. Is that the correct understanding or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Azure Boards Kanban Tools extension?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT: No.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

**First**, Kanban is mainly used to visualize the state or flow of your work. It is interactive in that you can change the state of the workitems as it progresses from one state to another. Kanban boards are not really dependent on sprint as such, but provide a cumulative flow chart for monitoring progress. It is the *Taskboard* that is tied to tracking the sprint tasks.

**Second**, the [WIP limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/wip-limits?view=azure-devops) are used to limit the number of workitems in progress, and can help identify process bottlenecks and improve the Team's efficiency. These numbers are set per stage and act as the soft constraint that can be revisited later.

And *yes*, you have to [create the iterations and iteration dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser), although they can be as per your pace, and [map your Team's work flow to Kanban columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/add-columns?view=azure-devops)!

Additional references:

- [Kanban Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-basics?view=azure-devops)
- [Kanban quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-quickstart?view=azure-devops)
- [What is Kanban?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/agile/what-is-kanban)
- If you want to re-evaluate your process model, give [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=azure-devops&tabs=basic-process) a prior reading.

Hope this clarifies!

Answer (score 0):

Well, Kanban cares about Flow. That requires some understanding of Queuing Theory. One aspect is for example Little´s Law. Which requires Delivery Rate. So I find it valid to ask for that metric (without iterations!) when Kanban is supposed to be supported.

Second, Kanban cares about Balance. eg between work arrival rate and work departure rate. Again it would be nice, if these metrics would be available out of the box.

(I teach Kanban courses BTW)

Something similar is required by DORA metrics: deployment frequency.
Which I assumed to be available out of the box in a product with "DevOps" in its name.